# Android "Service" not really in background?

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to play around with an Android "Service" but the more I play with it, the more I see that it's intimately tied to the UI thread.  What I mean is that I fire up an Activity, and call a Service, just for yucks do a very long for loop in the Service.  I would expect that for loop to happen in the "background" and not interfere with my UI, but it's freezing my UI while the for loop is going on (and it releases my UI back to normal when the for loop is done).  Why wouldn't the "Service" just run in the "background" instead of messing up my UI?  How can I make it run in the "background"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[from the manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> ### What is a Service?
>
> Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what
>   it is not:
>
> 1. A Service is **not** a separate process. The Service object itself does
>      not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise
>      specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part
>      of.
> 2. A Service is **not** a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off
>      of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

This is how you should do (again, taken from the manual & also mentioned by @Jave):

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work. More information on this can be found in [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html). The [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class is available as a standard
>   implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules
>   its work to be done.

Comment: Sounds to me like AsyncTask is what I'm after.

Comment: depend on what you want to do and how you want to architect your application.

Comment: @ariefbayu : So u mean IntentService is doing its job in separate thread than main thread of application

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for `Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> Note that services, like other application objects, **run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process.** This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work. More information on this can be found in [Processes and
>   Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html). The [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class is available as a standard
>   implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules
>   its work to be done.

Comment: Basically I'm using a SOAP webservice to update a SQLite table in my app.  I'd like to go into the Activity that displays this SQLite data, pop the data right away, and then update the SOAP stuff in the "background" without making the user wait.  The problem is that the app has many different Activities and the SOAP stuff gets interrupted or killed in my AsyncTask as I navigate around.  So I was shooting for a separate thread/service to do this but I learned that Services don't really work that way.

Comment: You *can* use a service that way, you just need to make it use a separate thread yourself.

Comment: That's up to you :p choose one that you think helped you the most.
Anyways, if you have a AsyncTask that is working, just move it into the service and you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DownloadingService extends Service
{
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        ...
        // Start up the thread running the service. Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.
        Thread notifyingThread = new Thread(null, mTask, "DownloadingService");
        notifyingThread.start();
    }

    private Runnable mTask = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // here the job is going to be done
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Intriguing.  I wouldn't be surprised if the experts say that's not recommended, though.  Either way I'm going to experiment with it now.  Thanks!