# Network Intense Operation Android

Tags: android, android-service

I have scenario where i receive SMS continuously to our handset , now i have read these SMS and upload data to a web service. After uploading the data , i have to again upload the same data just to verify weather its saved or not .

Now I have written a code some what like this ..
 
1) Broadcast receiver save SMS to DB (update UI for same) 
2) Service for Reading DB and upload ,verifying it . (Using intent service,update UI for same) .

And other set of service for Sending SMS 
 
1) Intentservice for checking data on server and sending sms based on it . 
 
2) Updating the status of Phone No on which sms has been saved (update on sever).

Now my issue it .. if i increase the no of SMS receiving per second , my application go crazy showing ANR which not error in logcat,sometimes says DB is not open . **So can someone suggest a nice design model for doing the same**

*Note: i have all code ready so let me know if u want to see code*

Comment: You have to use Content Providers for your DataBase, and make it not exposed. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: May be, in case of Broadcast receiver, you can save SMS to DB in another thread then the Main thread. Because, if you receive many SMSs then it makes sense to do that.

Comment: @VendettaDroid : I can try that ... can u also suggest me way by which i can update the ListView based on the same DB . Right now i fetching result from a query , which doesnt responsed as DB is too busy (this is fired everytime new data is saved).. I get errors like illegalstate expection .

Comment: Please can you confirm, that you are using only your Content Provider to access data. The implementation of content provider insure that all client will be served asyn. I thing that your are accessing data from multiple DBadapter.

Comment: No , i am not using COntent Provider for Accessing DB .. i have create a static object of Helper class so as get single object every-time ... And i also believe that SYNC is a issue in my current design .. Pls share ur design ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand why you upload the same data twice. You stated you upload with a HTTP (I guess it's a POST). Then your server will block, try to save the data and return a string like `OK` if it succeeded, or `KO` if it failed.

The ANR happens when [the main thread blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298268/315306), and by default both `Service`s and `BroadcastReceiver`s run in this thread. You may want to take a look at [the official Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Regarding the overall design, if the number of incoming SMS is very large, I suggest to batch upload every 5 minutes or so. You put all the messages in a queue, and every 5 minutes a service reads the queue and uploads its contents. This way you save a lot of overhead (CPU, memory, bandwidth, time), ane maybe you can keep up with the ratio  of data feeding.

Remember that a SMS is way more lightweight then a TCP communication, so if your device really *continuously* receives SMSs, you may end up with a situation where the writing speed can't keep up with the reading speed, finally starving the CPU and killing your system.

Comment: Thanks for solution . Uploading data second time for checking data has  been saved successfully or not.  DO u knw how to read Traces.txt file .

Comment: Successfully saved **where**? On the server? On the device?

Comment: Data is saved successfully on server

Comment: This is a waste of resources. You need a single upload. The server will take care of checking it for you and will respond accordingly. What protocol do you use? HTTP? FTP?

Comment: HTTP...Pls also suggest me if u better for making successful upload .  can u please check the description of my project .. i have another set of service which i forgot to mention earlier .

Comment: Simply make your server return a string like `OK` if it managed to save the data. See my updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17111/discussion-between-mohit-sharma-and-raffaele)